# rank on two dates - each date iteratively

Tags: sql, oracle, analytics

How to query for rank over 'value' for each day in the below table? Ex: IT should list out the 'mydate', 'value', 'rank' for all values on 20th and then do a fresh rank() for all values on 21st? Thanks...

```
create table tv (mydate,value)
as
select to_date('20/03/2010 00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),98 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 01','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),124 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 02','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),140 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 03','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),138 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 04','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),416 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 05','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),196 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 06','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),246 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 07','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),176 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 08','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),124 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 09','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),128 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 10','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),32010 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 11','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),384 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 12','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),368 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 13','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),392 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 14','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),374 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 15','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),350 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 16','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),248 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 17','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),396 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 18','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),388 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 19','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),360 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 20','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),194 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 21','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),234 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 22','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),328 from dual union all
select to_date('20/03/2010 23','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),216 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 00','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),224 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 01','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),292 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 02','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),264 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 03','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),132 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 04','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),142 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 05','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),328 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 06','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),184 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 07','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),240 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 08','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),224 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 09','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),496 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 10','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),370 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 11','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),352 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 12','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),438 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 13','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),446 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 14','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),426 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 15','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),546 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 16','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),546 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 17','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),684 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 18','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),568 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 19','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),504 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 20','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),392 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 21','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),256 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 22','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),236 from dual union all
select to_date('21/03/2010 23','dd/mm/yyyy HH24'),168 from dual
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Want ordered by time:

```
SELECT mydate
       , value
       , rank() over (partition by trunc(mydate) order by mydate)   
FROM tv;
```

Want ordered by value:

```
SELECT mydate
      , value
      , rank() over (partition by trunc(mydate) order by value) 
FROM tv;
```

Comment: "partition by trunc(mydate)" would work too.
PS. Your data sample has "21/03/10" converted through YYYY, giving year 0010.

Comment: Good call, changed to reflect.

Comment: I edited your response, because I have tested your queries and they do work